# Flash as3: Multiline htmlText scrolls on drag selection of text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, htmltext

Multiline htmlText scrolls on drag selection of text

It also scroll on mouse wheel event..

```
var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
css.parseCSS('.red-text{font-family:"Lucida Grande";color:#ED1C24;font-size:10;font weight:bold;leading:-8;}');                 

dynamicText.styleSheet = css;
dynamicText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
dynamicText.embedFonts = true;
dynamicText.multiline = true;
dynamicText.wordWrap = true;
dynamicText.htmlText = "<p class= 'red-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor consequat. </p>";

dynamicText.width = 450;
dynamicText.height = dynamicText.textHeight;
```

any fixes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the scroll wheel with `dynamicText.mouseWheelEnabled = false`. Also you should set `dynamicText.height = dynamicText.textHeight + 4;` because the text field has a padding of 2 pixel around the text (see [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html))

Answer (score 2):

```
field.addEventListener(Event.SCROLL, _scroll);
function _scroll(e:Event):void
{
    e.target.scrollV = 0;
}
```